# Streaming a file (like a song)

Tags: java, file, streaming, protocols, transfer

I have a file a want to send between two java programs. However the file may be too big (several megabytes) so by the time the other java program tries to use the file (waiting longer is not an option) its not completely downloaded.  Is there a "file streaming protocol" that can be used here in Java? So the device can use the file as its being downloaded?